# Python class constructor not working, too many arguments given

Tags: python, django

I didn't write "Django" in the question cause I don't think it is relevant. I have a Django Test that starts like this:

```
class APITests(APITestCase):

    def __init__(self):

        self.token = ""
        self.fixtures = ['tests/testdata.json']
        super(APITests, self).__init__()
```

It doesn't work, it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Could anyone explain me why? how can I solve this?

Comment: On what line do you get this error? Can you give the trace?

Comment: You should pass `self` as parameter to `super(APITests, self).__init__()`.

Comment: Every Python question should include the whole stack trace and the line that is indicated by the stack trace. Show the class instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should actually override `__init__` for `APITestCase`. I think they provide special `setup` and `teardown` methods that can be overridden.

But if you really have to override it, make sure you accept all arguments that are passed by the testing framework:

```
class APITests(APITestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.token = ""
        self.fixtures = ['tests/testdata.json']
        super(APITests, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

or define them as class attributes:

```
class APITests(APITestCase):
    tokens = ""
    fixtures = ('tests/testdata.json')
    ...
```